# Como criar uma função fatorial usando o contador 'for'?

Tags: javascript, for, fatorial

Vamos ao ponto:

Gostaria de criar uma **função fatorial** usando o contador `for` que calcule o fatorial do parâmetro `numero`.

Lembrando que `0! = 1` e `1! = 1`.

Meu código está assim:

```
function fatorial (numero) {
let num = 1;

for (let i = numero; i > numero; i--) {
    num *= num(i);
     }
     return num;
}
```

O raciocínio deve ser algo simples nada muito mirabolante que fuja deste meu código.

Mensagem de erro:

> expected 1 to equal 2

Penso que este raciocínio do fatorial possa ajudar:

> n! = n(n-1).(n-2)...3.2.1

Comment: Você está tentando invocar `num`, que não é uma função, mas um número.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem um problema de sintaxe que não faz sentido transforma `num` em função e usar ali, sei porque tem aquilo.

Além disso a condição de término do laço é quando chegar no 1 já que não precisa multiplicar mais nada. Do jeito que está nunca executará o laço já que a condição já começa inválida sempre, afinal a condição verifica se o `o` é maior que o `numero`, mas logo antes o código disse que `i` é igual ao `numero` então já é falso.

```js
function fatorial(numero) {
    let num = 1;
    for (let i = numero; i > 1; i--) {
        num *= i;
    }
    return num;
}
console.log(fatorial(5));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Factorial.js).

Answer (score 0):

Recentemente fiz um código parecido com esse, no qual queria fazer a multiplicação decrescente, mas no final percebi que não era necessário então fiz da forma mais simples:

```js
function fatorial(n) {
    var resultado = 1;
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        resultado *= i;
    }
    return resultado;
}
console.log(fatorial(2));
console.log(fatorial(3));
console.log(fatorial(4));
console.log(fatorial(5));
```

Obs: inicio o ciclo em 1 porque se começar em 0 sempre resultará em zero.